# Google Cloud Datastore query.add_filter doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I've managed to save some data to Google Cloud Datastore and now I'm planning on querying it to get meaningful data out.

I've tried to follow [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries) as well as I can, but I cannot get add_filter to work properly with floats.

In this query, I'm trying to find all products that have `currentPrice` over 500, but instead I get all results just sorted with `currentPrice`:

```
from google.cloud import datastore

def create_client(project_id):
    return datastore.Client(project_id)

client = create_client('product-catalog')
query = client.query(kind='Product')

query.add_filter('currentPrice', '>', 500)

for result in query.fetch():
    for key in result:
        print(key+"("+str(type(result[key]))+"): "+str(result[key]))
    print('---')
```

returns:

```
title(<class 'str'>): Cheap Oven
url(<class 'str'>): /product/343
currentPrice(<class 'float'>): 109.0
createdAt(<class 'datetime.datetime'>): 2018-03-22 19:52:02.173806+00:00
---
title(<class 'str'>): Regular Oven
url(<class 'str'>): /product/1231
currentPrice(<class 'float'>): 549.0
createdAt(<class 'datetime.datetime'>): 2018-03-21 03:25:24.622558+00:00
---
title(<class 'str'>): Expensive Oven
url(<class 'str'>): /product/4234
currentPrice(<class 'float'>): 2399.0
createdAt(<class 'datetime.datetime'>): 2018-03-23 22:46:01.571207+00:00
---
```

I was expecting for my query to result only `Regular Oven` and `Expensive Oven`.

For clarity, I've only included three results, but in my actual code there are over 50 000 products and I've verified, that the query results all products sorted by currentPrice and it is not just coincidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have already found the solution to your issue, but let me just provide some more details about why `> 500` and `> 500.0` does not return the same type of content, so that it can be better understood why the reported behavior happened.

For Datastore, [Floating-point numbers](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#floating-point_number) and [Integers](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#integer) are completely different and independent property types. In this case, as explained in the section about [how Datastore performs ordering by value type](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#value_type_ordering), integers are sorted before floats, in such a way that any value with Float type will be greater than any value with Integer type:

```
5 < 7   ---   5.0 < 7.0   ---   7 < 5.0
```

That is the reason why, when you were working with the filter `query.add_filter('currentPrice', '>', 500)`, all entities were being returned, because in this case, all the prices (of Float type) were greater than `500` (of Integer type):

```
500 < 109.0   ---   500 < 549.0   ---   500 < 2399.0
```

Therefore, when applying filters to queries in Datastore, you should work with the same property type as the one of the property you are trying to filter by.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

After doing some tests, I found out that the problem was that there was integer in the query, when the corresponding values were floats. Changing 500 -> 500.0 fixed this.

So this works correctly:

```
from google.cloud import datastore

def create_client(project_id):
    return datastore.Client(project_id)

client = create_client('product-catalog')
query = client.query(kind='Product')

query.add_filter('currentPrice', '>', 500.0)

for result in query.fetch():
    for key in result:
        print(key+"("+str(type(result[key]))+"): "+str(result[key]))
    print('---')
```

returns:

```
title(<class 'str'>): Regular Oven
url(<class 'str'>): /product/1231
currentPrice(<class 'float'>): 549.0
createdAt(<class 'datetime.datetime'>): 2018-03-21 03:25:24.622558+00:00
---
title(<class 'str'>): Expensive Oven
url(<class 'str'>): /product/4234
currentPrice(<class 'float'>): 2399.0
createdAt(<class 'datetime.datetime'>): 2018-03-23 22:46:01.571207+00:00
---
```